# Language setting for spell-check in Pages

Tags: pages, iwork, language, spellcheck

I'm new to Pages (from iWork) and have troubles with the spell-check function. It's simply not working for me.

*Almost everything is underlined red. No matter what language I write in.* I did not write paragraphs with mixed languages when checking. I used one language per trial.

- **How can I check what dictionary I'm using?** (I fear I might have none installed.)
- **Can I change the language for spell-check, without changing the system language?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspector > Text > More > Language

Comment: That's really hidden!