# How to change the spell check language in Pages 5?

Tags: macos, pages, internationalization, language, spellcheck

The solutions described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/how-do-i-set-the-default-language-in-pages) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35896/language-setting-for-spell-check-in-pages) are no longer available in the current version.

I am editing a document in Romanian but every word gets spell-checked in English.

[image]

Comment: Have you gone to Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar to set the dictionary to what you want?

Comment: Yes. I think that is the correct way to do it, but Romanian isn't in the list and there is not a choice for 'Other'. The best thing to do is probably to turn off the spell checker (from Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Check Spelling While Typing (AND Correct Spelling Automatically).

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, you are right of course. The only other fix would be add a Romanian dictionary if you can find one.  http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2011/06/extra-spell-checking-dictionaries-for.html

Comment: How to set a language for the whole document should be in the [Pages 5 help page](http://help.apple.com/pages/mac/5.2/#/tanf3d8c3e49) but isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually an OS X issue and not a Pages issue since Pages uses the system dictionaries.

You can use this support article to find the answer:

- http://help.apple.com/pages/mac/5.2/#/tanf3d8c3e49

You will see that Romanian spelling dictionary isn't something that ships with 10.11 - but you can add custom dictionaries under the spell check multiple language section at the bottom of the page.

1. Open System Preferences on your Mac, click Keyboard, then click Text. *(System Preferences is under the Apple menu at the top-left corner of your computer screen.)*
2. Choose Set Up from the Spelling pop-up menu.
3. Do any of the following:

   - Drag the languages in the list into the order you want them checked.
   - Select the checkbox next to languages you want to be checked.
   - If you have a dictionary file you want to use, copy it to the Spelling folder in your Library folder.

The last option is what you need. You could start with a free dictionary and perhaps pay for a better one if you can't make a dictionary or locate/make a better free one.

- https://github.com/dummas/Dictionaries

The panel where you get instructions to add the Romanian (or other) files looks like this:

[image]